# jquery apply css to all child elements of closest div

Tags: jquery, css

I'm looking to apply css not only to the closest 'div', but to all child elements of the div.

The code i have at the moment looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".classname").closest('div').css({"background-color": "purple"});
});
```

This only puts a background on the div, which contains eight white select boxes, i'd like them all to have the same background color.

With regular css i'd do this by .classname > *{background-color:red;}

The html is similar to

```
<div>
<select>
<option class="classname"></option>
</select>
<select>
<option class="other"></option>
</select>
<select>
<option class="other"></option>
</select>
<select>
<option class="other"></option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML structure? Also, your CSS selector and the jQuery selector are doing different things.

Comment: Attempted to add code on mobile

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery .children

```
$(".classname").closest('div').css({"background-color": "purple"});
$(".classname").closest('div').children().css({"background-color": "purple"});
```

Comment: Thank you, the .children() option was what i was looking for in conjunction with the .closest(div). Do you know if there is anyway to have have apply this to any element, that has a class name that contains certain characters e.g.... $(".*class* ").children().css({"background-color": "purple"});

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS example applies the background to all the direct children of .classname.
To achieve the same result using jQuery you can do the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".classname").children().css({"background-color": "purple"});
});
```

The 'closest' function in jQuery looks for the closest ancestor of the selected element that matches the selector, starting from the element itself. In your code, .classname seems to be a div, so .closest('div') matches the element itself (having no effect) and the background is applied to it.

Comment: Thank you, the .children() option was what i was looking for in conjunction with the .closest(div). Do you know if there is anyway to  have have apply this to any element, that has a class name that contains certain characters e.g.... $(".*class* ").children().css({"background-color": "purple"});

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code below

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var purpleBackgroundCss  = {"background-color": "purple"};
    $(".classname").closest('div').css(purpleBackgroundCss).children('div').css(purpleBackgroundCss);
    });
```

Comment: Hi Mina, thanks for your reply, this works however it seems that you are able to just use define the css once e.g. $(".classname").closest('div').children().css({"background-color": "purple"});